# Getting "Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. "

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I suddenly started getting below error when i click "Workflow" option at top ribbon of List/Library.

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Then i tried to publish workflow from SharePoint desinger and got below error:

> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementException: A response was
>   returned that did not come from the Workflow Manager. Status code =
>   403:  Access Denied    
>  
>       Access Denied (policy_denied) 
>  
>       Your system policy
>   has d

Please help.

Comment: Is the server up? Check if SharePoint still is connected to the wf server from central admin > service applications.

Comment: Yes servers are up. It is giving "Access denied" error. But i am not able to locate the point of the error.

Comment: One more finding:  I am able to click "Workflow" option from application servers but same is not working on WFEs.

Comment: ULS Log:                             Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementException: A response was returned that did not come from the Workflow Manager. Status code = 403:  <HTML><HEAD>  <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>  </HEAD>  <BODY>  <FONT face="Helvetica">  <big><strong></strong></big><BR>  </FONT>  <blockquote>  <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">  <TR><TD>  <FONT face="Helvetica">  <big>Access Denied (policy_denied)</big>  <BR>  <BR>  </FONT>  </TD></TR>  <TR><TD>  <FONT face="Helvetica">  Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL.

Comment: Got below error from Verbose:The schema for field with this name is wrong or missing .  field 'IconOverlay'.